# How to speed up simple linear algebra optimization probelm in Julia?

Tags: optimization, julia, linear-algebra, grid-search

I implemented the LSDD changepoint detection method decribed in [1] in Julia, to see if I could make it faster than the existing python implementation [2], which is based on a grid search that looks for the optimal parameters.

I obtain the desired results but despite my best efforts, my grid search version of it takes about the same time to compute as the python one, which is still way too long for real applications.
I also tried using the Optimize package which only makes things worse (2 or 3 times slower).

Here is the grid search that I implemented :

```
using Random
using LinearAlgebra

function squared_distance(X::Array{Float64,1},C::Array{Float64,1})
    sqd = zeros(length(X),length(C))
    for i in 1:length(X)
        for j in 1:length(C)
            sqd[i,j] = X[i]^2 + C[j]^2 - 2*X[i]*C[j]
        end
    end
    return sqd
end

function lsdd(x::Array{Float64,1},y::Array{Float64,1}; folds = 5, sigma_list = nothing , lambda_list = nothing)
    lx,ly = length(x), length(y)
    b = min(lx+ly,300)
    C = shuffle(vcat(x,y))[1:b]
    CC_dist2 = squared_distance(C,C)
    xC_dist2, yC_dist2 = squared_distance(x,C), squared_distance(y,C)
    Tx,Ty = length(x) - div(lx,folds), length(y) - div(ly,folds)
    #Define the training and testing data sets
    cv_split1, cv_split2 = floor.(collect(1:lx)*folds/lx), floor.(collect(1:ly)*folds/ly)
    cv_index1, cv_index2 = shuffle(cv_split1), shuffle(cv_split2)
    tr_idx1,tr_idx2 = [findall(x->x!=i,cv_index1) for i in 1:folds], [findall(x->x!=i,cv_index2) for i in 1:folds]
    te_idx1,te_idx2 = [findall(x->x==i,cv_index1) for i in 1:folds], [findall(x->x==i,cv_index2) for i in 1:folds]
    xTr_dist, yTr_dist = [xC_dist2[i,:] for i in tr_idx1], [yC_dist2[i,:] for i in tr_idx2]
    xTe_dist, yTe_dist = [xC_dist2[i,:] for i in te_idx1], [yC_dist2[i,:] for i in te_idx2]

    if sigma_list == nothing
        sigma_list = [0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.2, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 2.2, 3, 5]
    end
    if lambda_list == nothing
        lambda_list = [1.00000000e-03, 3.16227766e-03, 1.00000000e-02, 3.16227766e-02,
       1.00000000e-01, 3.16227766e-01, 1.00000000e+00, 3.16227766e+00,
       1.00000000e+01]
    end
    #memory prealocation
    score_cv = zeros(length(sigma_list),length(lambda_list))
    H = zeros(b,b)
    hx_tr, hy_tr = [zeros(b,1) for i in 1:folds], [zeros(b,1) for i in 1:folds]
    hx_te, hy_te = [zeros(1,b) for i in 1:folds], [zeros(1,b) for i in 1:folds]
    #h_tr,h_te = zeros(b,1), zeros(1,b)
    theta = zeros(b)

    for (sigma_idx,sigma) in enumerate(sigma_list)
        #the expression of H is different for higher dimension
        #H = sqrt((sigma^2)*pi)*exp.(-CC_dist2/(4*sigma^2))
        set_H(H,CC_dist2,sigma,b)
        #check if the sum is performed along the right dimension
        set_htr(hx_tr,xTr_dist,sigma,Tx), set_htr(hy_tr,yTr_dist,sigma,Ty)
        set_hte(hx_te,xTe_dist,sigma,lx-Tx), set_hte(hy_te,yTe_dist,sigma,ly-Ty)
        for i in 1:folds
            h_tr = hx_tr[i] - hy_tr[i]
            h_te = hx_te[i] - hy_te[i]
            #set_h(h_tr,hx_tr[i],hy_tr[i],b)
            #set_h(h_te,hx_te[i],hy_te[i],b)
            for (lambda_idx,lambda) in enumerate(lambda_list)
                set_theta(theta,H,lambda,h_tr,b)
                score_cv[sigma_idx,lambda_idx] += dot(theta,H*theta) - 2*dot(theta,h_te)
            end
        end
    end
    #retrieve the value of the optimal parameters
    sigma_chosen = sigma_list[findmin(score_cv)[2][2]]
    lambda_chosen = lambda_list[findmin(score_cv)[2][2]]
    #calculating the new "optimal" solution
    H = sqrt((sigma_chosen^2)*pi)*exp.(-CC_dist2/(4*sigma_chosen^2))
    H_lambda = H + lambda_chosen*Matrix{Float64}(I, b, b)
    h = (1/lx)*sum(exp.(-xC_dist2/(2*sigma_chosen^2)),dims = 1) - (1/ly)*sum(exp.(-yC_dist2/(2*sigma_chosen^2)),dims = 1)
    theta_final =  H_lambda\transpose(h)
    f = transpose(theta_final).*sum(exp.(-vcat(xC_dist2,yC_dist2)/(2*sigma_chosen^2)),dims = 1)
    L2 = 2*dot(theta_final,h) - dot(theta_final,H*theta_final)
    return L2
end

function set_H(H::Array{Float64,2},dist::Array{Float64,2},sigma::Float64,b::Int16)
    for i in 1:b
        for j in 1:b
            H[i,j] = sqrt((sigma^2)*pi)*exp(-dist[i,j]/(4*sigma^2))
        end
    end
end

function set_theta(theta::Array{Float64,1},H::Array{Float64,2},lambda::Float64,h::Array{Float64,2},b::Int64)
    Hl = (H + lambda*Matrix{Float64}(I, b, b))
    LAPACK.posv!('L', Hl, h)
    theta = h
end

function set_htr(h::Array{Float64,1},dists::Array{Float64,2},sigma::Float64,T::Int16)
    for (CVidx,dist) in enumerate(dists)
        for (idx,value) in enumerate((1/T)*sum(exp.(-dist/(2*sigma^2)),dims = 1))
            h[CVidx][idx] = value
        end
    end
end

function set_hte(h::Array{Float64,1},dists::Array{Float64,2},sigma::Array{Float64,1},T::Int16)
    for (CVidx,dist) in enumerate(dists)
        for (idx,value) in enumerate((1/T)*sum(exp.(-dist/(2*sigma^2)),dims = 1))
            h[CVidx][idx] = value
        end
    end
end

function set_h(h,h1,h2,b)
    for i in 1:b
        h[i] = h1[i] - h2[i]
    end
end
```

The set_H, set_h and set_theta functions are there because I read somewhere that modifying prealocated memory in place with a function was faster, but it did not make a great difference.
To test it, I use two random distribution as input data :

```
x,y = rand(500),1.5*rand(500)
lsdd(x,y) #returns a value around 0.3
```

Now here is the version of the code where I try to use Optimizer :

```
function Theta(sigma::Float64,lambda::Float64,x::Array{Float64,1},y::Array{Float64,1},folds::Int8)
    lx,ly = length(x), length(y)
    b = min(lx+ly,300)
    C = shuffle(vcat(x,y))[1:b]
    CC_dist2 = squared_distance(C,C)
    xC_dist2, yC_dist2 = squared_distance(x,C), squared_distance(y,C)
    #the subsets are not be mutually exclusive !
    Tx,Ty = length(x) - div(lx,folds), length(y) - div(ly,folds)
    shuffled_x, shuffled_y = [shuffle(1:lx) for i in 1:folds], [shuffle(1:ly) for i in 1:folds]
    cv_index1, cv_index2 = floor.(collect(1:lx)*folds/lx)[shuffle(1:lx)], floor.(collect(1:ly)*folds/ly)[shuffle(1:ly)]
    tr_idx1,tr_idx2 = [i[1:Tx] for i in shuffled_x], [i[1:Ty] for i in shuffled_y]
    te_idx1,te_idx2 = [i[Tx:end] for i in shuffled_x], [i[Ty:end] for i in shuffled_y]
    xTr_dist, yTr_dist = [xC_dist2[i,:] for i in tr_idx1], [yC_dist2[i,:] for i in tr_idx2]
    xTe_dist, yTe_dist = [xC_dist2[i,:] for i in te_idx1], [yC_dist2[i,:] for i in te_idx2]
    score_cv = 0
    Id = Matrix{Float64}(I, b, b)
    H = sqrt((sigma^2)*pi)*exp.(-CC_dist2/(4*sigma^2))
    hx_tr, hy_tr = [transpose((1/Tx)*sum(exp.(-dist/(2*sigma^2)),dims = 1)) for dist in xTr_dist], [transpose((1/Ty)*sum(exp.(-dist/(2*sigma^2)),dims = 1)) for dist in yTr_dist]
    hx_te, hy_te  = [(lx-Tx)*sum(exp.(-dist/(2*sigma^2)),dims = 1) for dist in xTe_dist], [(ly-Ty)*sum(exp.(-dist/(2*sigma^2)),dims = 1) for dist in yTe_dist]
    for i in 1:folds
        h_tr, h_te = hx_tr[i] - hy_tr[i], hx_te[i] - hy_te[i]
        #theta = (H + lambda * Id)\h_tr
        theta = copy(h_tr)
        Hl = (H + lambda*Matrix{Float64}(I, b, b))
        LAPACK.posv!('L', Hl, theta)
        score_cv += dot(theta,H*theta) - 2*dot(theta,h_te)
    end
    return score_cv,(CC_dist2,xC_dist2,yC_dist2)
end

function cost(params::Array{Float64,1},x::Array{Float64,1},y::Array{Float64,1},folds::Int8)
    s,l = params[1],params[2]
    return Theta(s,l,x,y,folds)[1]
end

"""
Performs the optinization
"""

function lsdd3(x::Array{Float64,1},y::Array{Float64,1}; folds = 4)
    start = [1,0.1]
    b = min(length(x)+length(y),300)
    lx,ly = length(x),length(y)
    #result = optimize(params -> cost(params,x,y,folds),fill(0.0,2),fill(50.0,2),start, Fminbox(LBFGS(linesearch=LineSearches.BackTracking())); autodiff = :forward)
    result = optimize(params -> cost(params,x,y,folds),start, BFGS(),Optim.Options(f_calls_limit = 5, iterations = 5))
    #bboptimize(rosenbrock2d; SearchRange = [(-5.0, 5.0), (-2.0, 2.0)])
    #result = optimize(cost,[0,0],[Inf,Inf],start, Fminbox(AcceleratedGradientDescent()))
    sigma_chosen,lambda_chosen = Optim.minimizer(result)
    CC_dist2, xC_dist2, yC_dist2 = Theta(sigma_chosen,lambda_chosen,x,y,folds)[2]
    H = sqrt((sigma_chosen^2)*pi)*exp.(-CC_dist2/(4*sigma_chosen^2))
    h = (1/lx)*sum(exp.(-xC_dist2/(2*sigma_chosen^2)),dims = 1) - (1/ly)*sum(exp.(-yC_dist2/(2*sigma_chosen^2)),dims = 1)
    theta_final = (H + lambda_chosen*Matrix{Float64}(I, b, b))\transpose(h)
    f = transpose(theta_final).*sum(exp.(-vcat(xC_dist2,yC_dist2)/(2*sigma_chosen^2)),dims = 1)
    L2 = 2*dot(theta_final,h) - dot(theta_final,H*theta_final)
    return L2
end
```

No matter, which kind of option I use in the optimizer, I always end up with something too slow. Maybe the grid search is the best option, but I don't know how to make it faster... Does anyone have an idea how I could proceed further ?

[1] : http://www.mcduplessis.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Journal-IEICE-2014-CLSDD-1.pdf
[2] : http://www.ms.k.u-tokyo.ac.jp/software.html

Comment: I'm not able to run your code, because you didn't provide any input data. Can you give some example input? It's important to make a self-contained example that will run just by copy-pasting it. Two observations: There is no `shuffle` function, you have to provide it. I can tell just by glancing at your code that it is very inefficient, so it should be possible to get very significant speedups.

Comment: Two more comments: Firstly, `sum(X.^2)[i,:]` should not work at all. `sum(X.^2)` will return a scalar (single number), so it's not possible to slice that. Have you really tested this code? It does not look runnable to me. Secondly, this question does not look like a good fit for stack overflow. You should rather post it to https://discourse.julialang.org/latest to get help there, but make sure to mention that it was also posted here.

Comment: @DNF Oh sorry ! I noticed that the ```squarred_distance``` function that I copied here was an old, obviously not working version of it. I corrected this and provided input data in the edited version of my post. The ```shuffle()``` definitely exists, though it might be a new thing introduced in the 1.0 version of julia. I already posted on julia discourse for this matter but could not get any improvement so I decided to try my luck here ...

Comment: This seems more like a codereview question to me https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @OscarSmith Thanks, I will post it there.